# Remixd fails to run, cannot find web3-requestmanager

Tags: web3js, remix

I have installed remixd using NPM. If I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'web3-requestManager'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remixd/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-core/src/index.js:26:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

I have searched a lot of solutions for this, like installing `ethereum/web3.js` or using another version of the web3 package, but none works. How to fix?

Comment: I've fixed it by installing it locally. Make sure you run the local program.

Comment: Sry, сan you explain in detail how you solved this problem?

Comment: You can install remixd locally via `npm install remixd`. It will install remixd in your local `node_modules` directory. To see where this is, use `npm root` to see where it has installed. It will not link `remixd` to your global program (which you can call via comment line). Now find `remixd` in your local directory: go to your local `node_modules` directory and go to the `.bin` directory, where it stores all programs. Now in this directory call `remixd` and you will see it works. To finish, link this program so it runs globally and you can use it!

Comment: Thx a lot! Now I get an error: bash: remixd: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: remixd: line 2: `var Router = require('./router')

Comment: That's an error I did not get. It appears that it tries to get the Router package but it doesn't exist. Did you also try reinstalling remixd again? Maybe it somehow forgot this package?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21874)

Answer (score 0):

As request, here is an answer on how I fixed it.

Install remixd locally via `npm install remixd`. Find your local `node_modules` directory via `npm root` and move here. Now go to `.bin` directory inside this local `node_modules` directory. `remixd` will be here. Now call `remixd` in this directory and it will run. It doesn't appear to run globally, so you can fix this by linking this local program globally.

Answer (score 0):

If you uninstall remixd npm package and install remix-ide npm package instead, which includes remixd package as well, you’ll find remixd perfectly working and complete.

Type:

> npm uninstall -g remixd
>
> npm install -g remix-ide

then you will be able to run remix both pointing your browser to http://localhost:8080 (local, offline) AND to https://remix.ethereum.org/ (remote, online).

In both cases remixd will be available.

Simply click on the chain icon in the file explorer area and you are on board. Remixd is working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install remixd using npm but got several errors. However, yarn worked for me.
But it I got remixd command not found. To fix this I created a node project using `yarn init` and added the required remixd command in my package.json.

```
 "scripts": {
"start": "remixd -s /home/user/directory --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org" }
```

After this, I used `yarn run start`. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As of the day I am commenting remixd is outdated, hence the best solution if someone facing this would be to,

```
# uninstall globally installed remixd
npm uninstall -g remixd

# install the intended package by remix
npm i -g @remix-project/remixd
```

Ref : https://www.npmjs.com/package/remixd